# How to add text in new lines in an ejs file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs, node-modules

Right now I am trying to alter the body of my ejs file with javascript embedded.
Here is the code :

```
<body>
<%- include('navbar.ejs'); %>
  <div class="novel" id="title">
  <p>Novel Title</h3>
</div>
<div id="skip"><button>
    First
  </button>
  <button>
    Last
  </button></div>
<p>
<% for( let index = 0; index < text.length; index++ ) { %>
<%-  text[index] %>
<% } %>
```

In the for statement, the text variable is a list of a very long string that contains the text of a novel. And every item in the list is separated by the new line so now I want to print it out in the ejs file with each line in a new one.

In this case, it would be like doing

```
document.write("/n")
```

If it were to work on an ejs file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try testing every character against newline regex, and if true, add a `<br>`, else the character:

```
<% for( let index = 0; index < text.length; index++ ) { %>
<%-  (/\r\n|\n|\r/).test(text[index]) ? '<br>' : text[index] %>
<% } %>
```

or simply split the string by newline, which creates an array which you can join with `<br>`:

```
<%-  text.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/).join('<br>') %>
```

you should escape string by using `<%=` tags, which will require modifying the code.
One option would be to split the string, and then output escaped string along with your HTML newline:

```
<% const split = text.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/); %>

<% split.forEach(line => { %>

    <%= line %><br>

<% }); %>
```